# redefine NSLog in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I Have a question about Xcode and Objective-C.

I want to make this simple action in Xcode:

If I type this :

```
NSLog(@"something else");
```

I want Xcode to write (or execute after compile):

```
NSLog(@"[%@] something else", NSStringFromClass([self class]));
```

Another way could be for Xcode 4 to suggest this in the autocomplete menu, when I type NSLog...

Comment: BTW, for debugging I suggest using `@"%s: something else", __FUNCTION__` instead, it will output something along the line of `- [MyClass myMethod]: something else`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a complete set of Log #define directives  (including **ULog**, a **UIAlertView** based Logging feature)

```
// DLog will output like NSLog only when the DEBUG variable is set

#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif

// ALog will always output like NSLog

#define ALog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);

// ULog will show the UIAlertView only when the DEBUG variable is set 

#ifdef DEBUG
#   define ULog(fmt, ...)  { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s\n [Line %d] ", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__] message:[NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__]  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show]; }
#else
#   define ULog(...)
#endif
```

As written by [Ciryon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22012/ciryon), just put them in your precompiled header (.pch) file.

(source: http://overbythere.co.uk/blog/2012/01/alternatives-nslog)

Answer (score 1):

You probably rather want to make a macro and put it in your precompile header (.pch) file.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```

(Taken from [this blog post](http://kusno.mudiarto.com/2009/06/nslog-replacement/))

Comment: The semicolon between the `@"%s [Line %d] "` and `fmt` makes this error out.  It should just be a space.

Comment: Thanks, fixed in case someone would copy/paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you use some other very excellent alternative options available like SOSMAX or NSLogger as i have written about them here http://learning-ios.blogspot.com/2011/05/better-nslog-ing.html